# Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token. using Facebook PHP SDK5

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have the error "Graph returned an error: Invalid OAuth access token", what should I replace 'facebook_access_token' with? Do you see any other issues in this cakephp function?

Comment: upgrade to the latest php sdk, that´s the best answer you will get here

Comment: @luschn Can you send me a good documentation on how to do the upgrade? I have looked at some documentation and it was not that straightforward.

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-5-tutorial/

Comment: @luschn I have this error now, can you check what I am doing wrong now? I use cakephp for my website.

Comment: @luschn what I should replace ['facebook_access_token'] with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved to easyApache4 and built PHP 5.6 and it fixed the issue. Still running with SDK3 no issues. SDK5 never worked with me.